# Change Action of 'Done' Button on Virtual Keyboard Android

Tags: java, android

All- I looked at other questions relating to this topic and found out that according to the android development website: "the action key performs a "done" operation, typically meaning the IME will be closed." My question is **how do I edit the action of the done button to make it so it calls one of my methods instead of closing the IME?**
Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think this might have your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451119/dismiss-android-preferences-dialog-on-keyboard-action-done-press?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

**Best possible way**

Example for handling Enter key event

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt);
    txt.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
         {
           if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
           {
               Log.d(TAG, "enter_key_called");
           }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```